# Archunit: authorize access to a single class in a ruled out package

Tags: archunit

I have an ArchUnit rule that check that my `core.service` classes do not access `javax.persistence` nor `org.hibernate` classes:

```
@ArchTest
ArchRule only_sql_adapter_pull_jpa_dependencies =
    noClasses().that().resideOutsideOfPackage("..infrastructure.outbound.sql..")
        .should().accessClassesThat().resideInAnyPackage("javax.persistence..", "org.hibernate..");
```

The problem is that the following legitimate access to the `PersistenceException.getMessage` in one of my core.service class is flagged as an error:

```
package my.application.core.service

try {
    persistenceService.save(myOject);
} catch (PersistenceException e) {
    log.error("service failed with {}", e.getMessage());
    // the call to e.getMessage() raise an Architecture Violation
    // because PersistenceException is part of the javax.persistence package
}
```

I want my `core.service` classes to be refused access to classes in `javax.persistence` in general but allowed access to `javax.persistence.PersistenceException` and derived because this one access is legitimate.

How can I modify the ArchRule above to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the fluent API [`accessClassesThat()`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/lang/syntax/elements/ClassesShould.html#accessClassesThat()), you can use [`accessClassesThat(DescribedPredicate<? super JavaClass> predicate)`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/0.23.1/com/tngtech/archunit/lang/syntax/elements/ClassesShould.html#accessClassesThat(com.tngtech.archunit.base.DescribedPredicate)) with a composed predicate:

```java
import static com.tngtech.archunit.base.DescribedPredicate.not;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.JavaClass.Predicates.assignableTo;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.JavaClass.Predicates.resideInAnyPackage;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.lang.conditions.ArchPredicates.are;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.lang.syntax.ArchRuleDefinition.noClasses;

// ...

@ArchTest
ArchRule only_sql_adapter_pull_jpa_dependencies =
    noClasses().that().resideOutsideOfPackage("..infrastructure.outbound.sql..")
        .should().accessClassesThat(
            resideInAnyPackage("javax.persistence..", "org.hibernate..")
                .and(are(not(assignableTo(PersistenceException.class))))
        );
```

Unrelated to your question:
Did you consider using [`dependOnClassesThat`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/lang/syntax/elements/ClassesShould.html#dependOnClassesThat(com.tngtech.archunit.base.DescribedPredicate)), which is less specific than `accessClassesThat`?